# No error code, but output repeats itself until kernal is interrupted

Tags: python, if-statement

I am a bit new to coding and am trying to build a code in python that asks the user what country they are from, and based on the answer the code assigns a numerical output.

Unfortunately, every time I try to run this code, I do not get any errors, but instead, the code output just asks over and over again 'Enter Country Name' until I interrupt the kernel.

What can I do to remedy this? Any help would be very appreciated.

```
   #high income
   A = ("Aruba", "Andorra",
       "United Arab Emirates", "Antigua and Barbuda",
      "Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Bahrain", "Bahamas", "Bermuda", "Barbados")
   # Low income
   B = ("Afghanistan", "Burundi", "Zambia", "Burkina Faso", "Central African 
    Republic", "Syrian Arab Republic","Congo Dem. Rep")

 # Middle Income
    C = ("Angola", "Albania", "Argentina", "Armenia", "American Samoa", "Azerbaijan", 
    "Benin", "Bangladesh","Bulgaria")
 while True:
     user_input = input('Enter Country Name: ')
   total = 0.
   if user_input == A:
            total += 1
            print(total, "Added")
  elif user_input == B:
            total += 2
            print(total, "Added")
  elif user_input == C:
            total += 3
            print(total, "Added")
 else:
     print("country does not exist")
```

Answer (score 1):

In your while condition your mentioning `True` then it will run the set of statements till it gets `False`.

The while loop in Python is used to iterate over a block of code as long as the test expression (condition) is true.

```
cond = True
while cond:
    user_input = input('Enter Country Name: ')
    total = 0
    if user_input in A:
        total += 1
       print(total, "Added")
    elif user_input in B:
        total += 2
        print(total, "Added")
    elif user_input in C:
        total += 3
        print(total, "Added")
    else:
        print("country does not exist")
        cond = False
```

so in the above example first we are setting true in the variable on the end of while we are setting `cond` as `False` so the while will stop executing

Answer (score 0):

you are using a while loop with the True as condition. It is an infinite loop as True is always true. To make it work you need to insert a break condition in some of the if-else statements so that the code can exit the loop somewhen. Or you can rewrite your while statement to make the code more reasonable. I do not know exactly what you want to do but if you just want to ask the user for the input you do not need a while loop.

Hope this helped.